# Stanford CoreNLP Chinese coreference resolution

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to use stanford coreNLP to process some Chinese Coreference resolution.My code is below:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Mention;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

public class CorefTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StanfordCoreNLP pipline = new StanfordCoreNLP("StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties");
    Annotation document = new Annotation("奥巴马出生在夏威夷，他是美国总统，他在2008年当选");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    System.out.println("---");
    System.out.println("coref chains");
    for (CorefChain cc : document.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.class).values()) {
      System.out.println("\t" + cc);
    }
    for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println("---");
      System.out.println("mentions");
      for (Mention m : sentence.get(CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefMentionsAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println("\t" + m);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

And it give the result :

```
---
coref chains
---
mentions
    奥巴马出生在夏威夷 ， 他是美国总统 ， 他在2008年当选
```

Where nothing in the  coref chains,I do set the environment right, and it does support chinese , but how can I get coref chains right?

Answer (score 0):

You are making the pipeline twice in your code.

Note: make sure to add this to your code:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils;
```

You code should be like this:

```
Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties("-props", "StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties");
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,mention,coref");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
```